# iOS swift representing application view state in a dictionary of arrays of (tuples)

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying store application view state by storing it in array of tuples. Every tuple contains view, property and it's value. E.g. (button, "hidden", false").
So example of structure is following:

```
 var states = Dictionary<String, Array<(view: AnyObject, property: AnyObject, value:  AnyObject)>>()
```

But the problem is I can't extract values to set afterwards, when I iterate through that array like this:

```
for var tuple in states[stateName]! {
   tuple.view.hidden = tuple.value
   print(tuple.view, tuple.value)
}
```

"Can't assign to property" since tuple is immutable is received.

So two questions:

1. How to extract and set value properly.
2. (minor) May be there coulee be better representation of the state in terms of structure.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I'll struct the tuple like this.

```
struct tuple {
    var view: UIView
    var property: Any
    var value: Bool
    init(view: UIView, property: Any, value: Bool) {
        self.view = view
        self.property = property
        self.value = value
    }
}

var states = Array<Dictionary<String, tuple>>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set initial value
    var tuple1 = ["123" : tuple(view: UIView(), property: 2, value: false)]
    var tuple2 = ["456" : tuple(view: UIView(), property: 5, value: false)]

    // update value
    print(tuple1.keys.first)
    tuple1.updateValue(tuple(view: UIView(), property: 2, value: true), forKey: "123") // one way
    tuple1[tuple1.keys.first!]?.property = 3 // another way
    states = [tuple1, tuple2]

    for item in states {
        if item.keys.contains("123") {
            item["123"]?.view.isHidden = (item["123"]?.value)!
            print(item["123"]?.view.isHidden, item["123"]?.value, item["123"]?.property)
        }
    }
}
```